# WMTS : Convert geolocation (lat, long) to tile index, at a given zoom level?

Tags: convert, development, wmts

I wanted to know how to get the indexes (x,y) of a WMTS tile for a given geolocation (latitude, longitude) and zoom level.

For exemple, I have a POI located at (48.675, 2.7), I want to get the corresponding open-street-map tile for the zoom 10.

Can I do the math ? Do I need a webservice ?
Precision : I have to do this programmatically.

Comment: Here you go: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_map_tilenames#Lon..2Flat._to_tile_numbers_2

Comment: A useful [MSDN Article on the Bing Maps Tiling Scheme](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb259689.aspx) also provides a good primer. Both this and the OSM article assume Web Mercator projection, but the principle is the same for other projected co-ordinate systems.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The OSM wiki page is perfect : http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_map_tilenames#Lon..2Flat._to_tile_numbers_2

Here is the extracted answer (in pseudo code) for quick reference.

**Given Longitude/latitude/zoom to tile numbers :**

```
n = 2 ^ zoom
xtile = n * ((lon_deg + 180) / 360)
ytile = n * (1 - (log(tan(lat_rad) + sec(lat_rad)) / π)) / 2
```

Note that `log()` in this pseudo code refers to natural log (often "ln()" in common math syntax, but often "log()" in many programming languages).

**Given Tile numbers to longitude/latitude :**

```
n = 2 ^ zoom
lon_deg = xtile / n * 360.0 - 180.0
lat_rad = arctan(sinh(π * (1 - 2 * ytile / n)))
lat_deg = lat_rad * 180.0 / π
```

Comment: wait, the OSM slippy format is the WMTS tile format?

Comment: Note that the [link](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_map_tilenames) above has implementations in *many* languages! (27 currently)

Comment: Be aware that according to [this link](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_map_tilenames) , latitude goes from 0 to 85.0511 °N (not 90  °N) and from 0 to  85.0511 °S (not 90  °S). The number 85.0511 is the result of arctan(sinh(π)). By using this bound, the entire map becomes a (very large) square