# Transform coordinates to WMTS tiles in EPSG:4362

Tags: geoserver, wmts, mercator

How can I calculate the tiles numbers/names in EPSG:4362 based on lat, lon and zoom ?

Note that I was able to do it for EPSG:3857 Pseudo-Mercator, but the formula in [wikipedia](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_map_tilenames#Lon./lat._to_tile_numbers_2) and the one in [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/450732/find-geoserver-tile-name-by-lat-lon?noredirect=1#comment736379_450732) doesn't work for EPSG:4362

Comment: Convert to EPSG 3857 and then use whatever method you used that worked for that?  In what context are you doing this - a programming language or command line? What coordinate transform library do you have available (because coding a transform from scratch in maths is probably a bad idea).

Comment: Perhaps start with the OGC WMTS specification ~ https://portal.ogc.org/files/?artifact_id=35326

Comment: I am trying to generate .geojson tiles from Geoserver and then find the correct tile based on Lat,Lon and Zoom , but geojson is available only in EPSG 4326 (at least in Geoserver) ..

Comment: GeoJSON isn't EPSG:4326 (lat/lon) its CRS:84 (lon/lat).  That is the official GeoJSON standard not just GeoServer

Comment: 4326 can be lon/lat when it wants to be, that's what makes it fun to use. :-)